# How to read the balance on a wallet address

Tags: balance, bitcoinjs

So, first of all i will be creating these wallet addresses on my end using below code:

```
 const diviMainnet = {
                    messagePrefix: '\x19Divi Signed Message:\n',
                    bech32: 'divi',
                    bip32: {
                      public: 0x22d2533,
                      private: 0x221312b
                    },
                    pubKeyHash: 0x1e,
                    scriptHash: 0xd,
                    wif: 0xd4
                  }
                  const keyPair = ECPair.ECPair.makeRandom();
                  const { address } = bitcoin.payments.p2pkh({ pubkey: keyPair.publicKey, network: diviMainnet });
```

I am storing the WIF as below

```
     myWallet =     {
                    "pubKey": address,
                    "wif": keyPair.toWIF()
                  }
//save to db
```

now how do i check the balance of the above wallet at any point later?

I am using bitcoinjs library on nodejs.

Comment: Voting to close, because questions about altcoins are not on-topic for this site.

Answer (score 3):

To get a balance of the address you need a view of the blockchain's current utxo set. This is typically done by syncing a node. I don't believe bitcoinjs has the capability to be a node (nor it is recomended to use it as one if it does).

Using bitcoin core you could add it to the wallet and do a rescan.

Alternatively you can use something that requires more trust and ping a block explorer. Bitcoinjs has an example on how to do this here https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/test/integration/addresses.spec.ts#L10

Comment: const result = await dhttp({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/' + address,
      });

this part?

Comment: Also if you look at my question i am using a different blockchain https://diviproject.org

Comment: > const result = await dhttp({ method: 'GET', url: 'blockchain.info/rawaddr' + address, }); this part?

Yes